# calculate in function and call in another

Tags: python, function, program-entry-point

Writing a simple program to calculate in one function named results and calling it in the main function while accepting user input. I am getting an error message in main function my variable names getnum and answer are not found.

```
print ("Even or Odd Checker\n")

def results(num):

    if (num % 2) == 0:
        print("{0} is Even".format(num))
    else:
        print("{0} is odd".format(num))
    return num

def main():

    getnum = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    answer = results(num)
    print (answer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Maybe `results(num)` should be `results(getnum)`?

Comment: Can you add the trace of exact error you are getting?

Comment: make it a habit to name variable as a "thing", and a function as a "verb".
you are naturally pass `num` but the var assignment is `getnum`

Answer (score 2):

**It should be like this, in this scope variable num is not exist-->**

```
getnum = int(input("Enter a number: "))

answer = results(getnum)
```